# Chrome bug in wordpress search form

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I just working on site powered on WordPress CMS.
In IE,Firefox, Opera and other browser works fine, but on Chrome no.
On site http://dian.7u.cz in firefox the search form is in good position but on Chrome it is line under the true position.

I generate that button like this

```
<div id="topsearch">
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
</div>
```

Firefox make it like this

```
<div id="topsearch">
  <div id="search">
    <form id="searchform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/" method="get">
      <input id="s" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Hľadať') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '')  {this.value = 'Hľadať';}" name="s" value="Hľadať">    
      </input>
      <input type="image" style="border:0; vertical-align: top;"src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/GamesMax/GamesMax/images/search.gif">
      </input>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

but Chrome make it like this

```
<div id="topsearch">
 ""

  <div id="search">
    <form id="searchform" action="http://localhost/wordpress/" method="get">
      <input id="s" type="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Hľadať') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '')  {this.value = 'Hľadať';}" name="s" value="Hľadať">    
      </input>
      <input type="image" style="border:0; vertical-align: top;"src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/GamesMax/GamesMax/images/search.gif">
      </input>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css for topsearch is :

```
#topsearch {
    text-align:left;
    float:right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 17px;
    margin-top: 9px;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed it by adding a little hack to css:

```
#topsearch{
    font-size:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your search form like this:

```
 <!-- Search Box Begin-->
<div class="searchbox">
<form method="get" id="navsearchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/">
<input type="text" class="search-text" value="" name="s"  />
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</div>
<!-- Search Box End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your `header.php` and `searchform.php` template again and make sure there is no invisible space or tab characters.

It seems like an invisible space character in the end of the line between `#topsearch` and `#search`.

```
<div id="topsearch">
                    ﻿ 
    <div id="search">
        <form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://dian.7u.cz/">
```